# How do Rails associations look behind the scenes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Can anyone point to some resource which shows how the tables are set up ( for MySQL for example ), on each of the Rails associations ( one to one, one-to-many, many to many ). I understand how the associations work from a Rails point of view, but I don't understand how they work from the database's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html has images that detail the database columns.